# Splitting channels of one recording application to capture from two monitor sources in pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio, pavucontrol

I would like to have mixxx take input (e.g. aux1 and aux2) from two different monitor sources.

I tell mixxx to use pulseaudio as input for both aux1 and aux2 but set channels 1-2 and 3-4 respectively.

Then I have the following showing in `pavucontrol` and it's set to capture from "Monitor of built-in... HDMI"

[screenshot of pavucontrol recording tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrWoJ.png)

What I'd like is the 3rd and 4th channels to capture from "Monitor of XXX" where XXX is another output device (and channels 1+2 continue to capture from "Monitor of ... HDMI")

Could a pulseaudio wizard point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Or could I configure pulseaudio to expose two "pulses" to mixxx?  e.g. "pulse1" and "pulse2"

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out very simple, and my comment about exposing two "pulses" to mixxx was the clue.

Assuming you're using ALSA, in `~/.asoundrc` add the following section at the end

```
pcm.pulse2 {
  type pulse
}
```

and start mixxx.

When choosing input (or output) devices in mixxx, you'll see "pulse" and "pulse2" and you can assign these to different inputs (e.g. aux1 and mic1).  You can then set up the sources for these two inputs separately in pavucontrol.